# JSON object creation using PHP - from fetched values of database columns

Tags: php, json

I am new to PHP.
I am working on project of recommendation system.

here i am fetching values from database like "userid" and "items".

and, I want to create JSON object like this

```
{
    "john": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
    "alex": ["a", "b", "x", "y", "z"],
    "me": ["a", "b", "c", "f", "r"]
}
```

but what i am getting is

```
[
    {
        "john": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
    },
    {
        "alex": ["a", "b", "x", "y", "z"],
    },
    {
        "me": ["a", "b", "c", "f", "r"]
    }

]
```

this is the code what i have tried,

```
<?php

    include "init.php";//database connection

    $sql = "select * from Orders";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $userid = $row['userid'];
            $items = $row['items'];
            $itemsarray = explode(',', $items);

            if(!in_array($userid, array_keys($user_item))){
                $user_item[$userid] = $itemsarray;
            }
            else{
                 $values = $user_item[$userid];
                 $arr = array_merge($values,$itemsarray);
                 $user_item[$userid] = $arr;
           }
        }
    echo json_encode($user_item);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the key on the top level set. Otherwise PHP will convert it into a JSON array. Replace

```
$arr = [$userid => $itemsarray];
array_push($user_item, $arr);
```

with

```
$user_item[$userid] = $itemsarray;
```

Comment: thank u @Machavity, it worked.                                                                        what if there are multiple items with same key??

Comment: If they have the same key it will overwrite. You'll have to ask a separate question with a better explanation of what you want there